# How/why to create views outside of storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I've been reading a bit about State Preservation and Restoration from Apple's documentation, and wondering about using both storyboard and xibs in the same application. My question has two parts:

First- What are the benefits of using a xib for a view rather than just creating it in the storyboard? The only thing I can think of is when multiple tabs or navigation controllers lead to the same class of ViewController, and you don't want a mess of segue arrows in the storyboard.

Second- How would I create and display a modal TableViewController without using a xib or storyboard (in other words, creating the view in code, without an Interface Builder xib file)?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question:

## It's quite easy, and that's how it was/should be done

Just make a `UITableViewController` class, populate the methods with whatever you would normally do. Then, to use it:

```
 //Get Table View Controller
 MYTableViewController *tconn = [[MYTableViewController alloc] init];
 //Optional, add navigation controller
 UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tconn];
 //actually present it
 [self presentModalViewController:navCon animated:YES];
```

## Now, back to the 1st question

The main advantage to using Xib's instead of Storyboards comes with compatibility. iOS5+ supports Storyboards, everything supports Xib's.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Erway. I guess I need to re-phrase the question since this was closed-- The main point was "why use the combination of storyboard and xib?"